# Haskell function to check if two values are identical

Tags: haskell

In Haskell we have the function `(==) :: Eq a => a->a->Bool` which is fine for the large number of datatypes for which an instance of `Eq` can be defined.  However there are some types for which there is no reasonable way to define an instance of `Eq`.  one example is the simple function type `(a->b)`

I am looking for a function that will tell me if two values are actually the same -- not equal but identical.

For example `f(id,id)` ==> `True`  `f((+),(-))` = False

**Clarification:**

I *don't* want to know if two function do the same thing. It is not possible in the general case to do so.  I want to know if I've gotten back the same thing I started with. Let me give a stripped down example:

```
data Foo = Foo (Foo->Foo)  --contains a function so no Eq instance

x :: Foo
x = Foo id -- or for that matter Foo undefined

y :: Foo
y = Foo (const x)

a :: Foo
a = let (Foo fy) = y
     in fy x
```

It is clear that by inspection once evaluated, `a` will be `x`.  But let's assume I don't know the function in y but I want to test if the Foo I put in is the same one I got back - that is does `fy x` give me `x`. How do I do this?

Comment: Maybe the same question as this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717553/pointer-equality-in-haskell

Comment: I am almost sure you don't actually want this.

Comment: Values in pure functional programming have no identity like OOP objects.

Comment: It is nigh on impossible to compare two functions in Haskell. For instance, `Control.Applicative.<*>` and `Control.Monad.ap` are pretty much identical, but are incomparable because of their types.

Comment: What would you want the result of, say, `f (\x -> x+x) (\x -> 2*x)` to be?

Comment: If you solve the halting problem for me, I will solve this problem for you.

Comment: Leftroundabout: False.  They are not the same function.  Rein Henrichs, it is my inability to solve the halting problem that leads to my question.  I have a data structure that includes a function so I cannot create an Eq class for it.  They form a graph, and I need to know if I've looped back to the node I started from.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way that wasn't mentioned in [Pointer equality in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717553/pointer-equality-in-haskell) is [`reallyUnsafePtrEquality#`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.4.0.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#g:21). As the name suggests it can be unpredictable and probably should't be used but it can be interesting to see how ghc works. Here's how you can use it in ghci:

```
> :set -package ghc-prim
> import GHC.Prim
> import GHC.Types
> isTrue# (reallyUnsafePtrEquality# id id)
True
> let a x = x + 2 :: Int
> isTrue# (reallyUnsafePtrEquality# a a)
True
> let b x = x + 2 :: Int
> isTrue# (reallyUnsafePtrEquality# a b)
False
```

If the function isn't monomorphic it doesn't work:

```
> let c x = x + 2
> isTrue# (reallyUnsafePtrEquality# c c)
False
```

---

Some more examples:

```
> let d = c in isTrue# (reallyUnsafePtrEquality# d d)
False
> :set -XMonomorphismRestriction
> let d = c in isTrue# (reallyUnsafePtrEquality# d d)
True
```

You can compare polymorphic types if you wrap them in a newtype:

```
> :set -XRankNTypes
> newtype X = X (forall a. Num a => a -> a)
> let d = X c
> isTrue# (reallyUnsafePtrEquality# d d)
True
```

Applying anything makes them not equal

```
> isTrue# (reallyUnsafePtrEquality# (id ()) (id ()))
False
```

But when compiling with optimisations this is `True`.

Hopefully this is enough to convince you that what you want is a bad idea. One of the solutions in [Pointer equality in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717553/pointer-equality-in-haskell) would be a better.

Comment: @Sibi Right, my understanding is for `c :: Num a => a -> a`, `a` gets defaulted to `Integer` by ghci's default rules (because it needs to have some type). This means `c` gets "cloned" at each site and so they have different pointer values. On the other hand `id` doesn't need to select a specific type so it points to the same thing.