# Third Monoid Law and IO?

Tags: haskell

Looking at this `IO` code:

```
Prelude> let e = return () :: IO ()
Prelude> e `mappend` e
Prelude> let y = e `mappend` e
Prelude> :t y
y :: IO ()
```

**EDIT** Apparently, as I understand, `IO` has a `Monoid` instance.

However, shouldn't the following evaluate to `true`, in order to obey the Monoid third law?

```
Prelude> e `mappend` (e `mappend` e) == (e `mappend` e) `mappend` e

<interactive>:14:1: error:
    * No instance for (Eq (IO ())) arising from a use of `=='
    * In the expression:
        e `mappend` (e `mappend` e) == (e `mappend` e) `mappend` e
      In an equation for `it':
          it = e `mappend` (e `mappend` e) == (e `mappend` e) `mappend` e
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The third monoid law](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html) states that `e <> (e <> e) = (e <> e) <> e` (to use the easier-to-type infix operator for `mappend`), *not* that `e <> (e <> e) == (e <> e) <> e` (note the `=` vs. `==`).

It's expressing an equivalence -- really, expressing that `mappend` should be associative -- not demanding all `Monoid`s must also be instances of the `Eq` typeclass, where the `==` comes from.

Another way of saying this: it's expressing a high-level idea about the behavior of the `mappend` function, not presenting valid Haskell code that should evaluate to anything in particular.

Some types that are `Monoid`s -- like `[()]`, for instance -- also happen to have an `Eq` instance. But some (like the `IO ()` instance here) don't, and that's okay.

> Sidenote: It doesn't really make sense to give `IO` an `Eq` instance, because it's nigh on impossible to determine if a certain `IO ()` is equivalent to another `IO ()`. Is `putStrLn "3"` "equal" to `print 3`? They both have the same observable effects, but how on earth could the runtime determine that in the general case? And you can't say "they're equivalent if they produce the same values," because then the return type of `==` would have to be an `IO Bool`, and that's not the right signature for `Eq`. So we just don't give `IO` an `Eq` instance, and that's fine -- I can't come up with a reasonable example of when such an instance would be useful.

Also note that "`IO`" doesn't have a `Monoid` instance (it's the wrong kind, anyway). The `mappend` that you're using comes from the instance for `Monoid a => Monoid (IO a)` — that is, IO recipes to produce types which are themselves `Monoid`s. `IO`'s `Monoid` instance just "piggy-backs" on the underlying `Monoid` instance.

Comment: A valid, intuitively correct `Eq (IO a)` instance would be *tremendously* useful, if it were possible to write one. But Alan Turing will sit up in his grave and give you a tongue-lashing if you try.

Comment: @dfeuer I don't see the problem. After all, we have an `Eq [a]` instance.

Comment: @dfeuer @ReinHenrichs Surely it's about decidability rather than termination? `IO a` is (sorta) represented as `RealWorld -> (RealWorld, a)`. That arrow means an `Eq` instance would have to decide function equality, [which is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132051/is-finding-the-equivalence-of-two-functions-undecidable)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, his point was that infinite lists are fully general (computable) functions on natural numbers. I doubt equality for such functions is decidable either.