# How to tell if one Expression tree is a subset of another

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

Let's say I have

```
int id1 = 1;
int id2 = 2;
IQueryable<T> source = someSource;
IQueryable<T> predicate1 = source.Where(x => x.id1 = id1);
IQueryable<T> predicate2 = source.Where(x => x.id1 = id1 && x.id2 = id2);
```

Is there an easy way to find out, if all actions of predicate1 are done in predicate2? Like `predicate1.isChildOf(predicate2) = true 
and 
predicate2.isChildOf(predicate1) = false`

I would like to query a database and save results in memory. Given that I already made a query with not too restricting constraint, I could query it instead of a database.

**Edit:** 
At the time of new query, I have only previous datasets with corresponding predicates. Let's say (d(ata)1, p(redicate)1), (d2, p2). I prefer taking data from those datasets instead of database (less expensive), but some predicates are too restricting therefore I need to query the original database. Given a new predicate, p3, I need to find if d1 or d2 isn't 'filtered too much'. For example we have same predicates as in the original post and `p3 = source.Where(x => x.id3 == id3)`. Then I need to query the original database anyway. But if I have `p4 = source.Where(x => x.id1 = id1)` then I can simply take d1.

Comment: Can you talk us through why you want to know this? Extra context may help us to help you better.

Comment: Not really , i guess you'd have to compare the results

Comment: [mjwills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills), I've made an edit

Comment: So just query your query instead. Doesn't matter if you add the same constraints again.

Comment: You might get better answers if you ask something like "How to tell if one `Expression` tree is a subset of another"

Comment: [BurnsBA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1462295/burnsba) that's the exact question I was trying to formulate.

Comment: @user2820173 you are asking 2 distinctly different questions. One is about an expression being a subset of another expression (I can answer this), the other is about the results of both expressions. I think you're going to get wildly different answers unless you reword.

Comment: @Kit Where did they ask anything about the results of the expressions?  They only ever asked about comparing them before getting the results.  Remember that an `IQueryable` represents a query, *not the results of executing that query*.  It is not until you iterate over it that the query is actually executed.

Comment: You're right. I meant actions. Still actions vs. whether expression is a subset of another are two different things.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, determining if two functions produce the same value given the same input (defined as those functions being "equivalent") [is provably impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132051/is-finding-the-equivalence-of-two-functions-undecidable).  So from the start you can't solve the problem as you've asked it.  You can solve it for certain specific cases, for example, as mentioned, if two expressions are reference equal, then we know they'll be equivalent, but any solution you come up with is going to have either false positives or false negatives.

Just even trying to come up with some heuristics, outside of reference equality, for very simple cases where functions are equivalent is *very* hard, because there are lots of ways of showing how programs that have even the slightest of differences can potentially have different behaviors, at least in some edge conditions.

Trying to determine if the theoretical output values of one function will always be a subset of another, using any method other than an analysis of whether the return type of one method is equal or a subtype of another, is going to be *even harder*.

Answer (score 0):

Servy's answer is correct when addressing

> Is there an easy way to find out, if all actions of predicate1 are done in predicate2?

When you ask

> How to tell if one Expression tree is a subset of another

this is difficult but not impossible. You *can* determine if an expression is a subset of another expression because expressions are trees, and you can traverse and compare trees.

You would need to visit the nodes of each expression (btw, you would need to do this with the expressions, not simply on the lambdas, prior to getting the `IQueryable`). To visit you could use an [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor(v=vs.110).aspx) or roll your own by inspecting the types of the expressions.

A naïve algorithm would be to start at the root of each LINQ expression and compare its nodes. When you don't have a match you iterate to the children of the proposed supertree. If you get a match you iterate both trees. There will be some backtracking if you iterate part of the proposed subtree and then fail to match. This [page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-binary-tree-subtree-another-binary-tree-set-2/) has an example in C for a binary tree. You will need to have a more general algorithm.

You will need to take into account the expressions' type as this dictates what nodes are available (e.g. are they unary or binary expressions, etc.). You will need to take into account the types of the operands if you want to be fully generic with the solution.

You do *not* want to take into account the names of the operands, as they don't really matter when determining if you have a subgraph (e.g. the first is still a subset of the second):

```
x => x.id1 == id1
y => y.id1 == id1 && y.id2 == id2
```

Comment: The question specifically states that they want to figure out whether or not the results of executing a given query will all be within the set of results of another query (without actually executing either).  It doesn't ask to determine if the expression is syntactically a subset of another.  That's one approach that you might attempt to use in determining the actual question, but you'd need to do more than *just* that as containing a subset doesn't necessarily mean that the results will be a subset as well.

Comment: The title is specific too, changed by the OP for a reason in response to comments. So now we have two different sorts of questions; That was my point in my comments above: that the questions are different and so OP will get different answers.

Comment: The fact that a shortened summary didn't accurately convey the semantics of the actual question doesn't mean it's asking two different questions, it just means that the summary was wrong.  When they expanded on what the actual question they are asking is, they made it clear they're interested in comparing the potential output values of executing the queries, not the literal expressions.

Comment: Ok, but read OP's comments: *that's the exact question I was trying to formulate* to *You might get better answers if you ask something like "How to tell if one Expression tree is a subset of another"*. I think both of our answers cover the range of his questions. It wasn't a shortened summary; it was an intentional reformulation of what OP wanted. It seems all OP's actions and questions are contradictory, and gave us something to talk about :)

Comment: The OP was specific about what they're actually trying to do.  They're caching the results of certain queries and trying to determine if a given queries results are in the cache, or if they need to execute the query to get the results.  Knowing if one expression's tree is in another's doesn't actually help you accomplish that, so it's clear that that's *not* what they're asking.  That the summary in the title isn't even their own words only *supports* the idea that it's not what they're asking about.

Answer (score -1):

[Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Determines whether a sequence contains a specified element by using a specified IEqualityComparer

[ALL](http://Determines%20whether%20all%20elements%20of%20a%20sequence%20satisfy%20a%20condition.)

> Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

So, if `predicate2` contains all items of `predicate1`, we can conclude that `predicate1` is a child of `predicate2`.

```
predicate1.All(x=> predicate2.Contains(x)) == true  <--- predicate1 is child of predicate2

predicate2.All(x=> predicate1.Contains(x)) == false  <--- predicate2 isn't child of predicate1
```

You must be sure that you define `IEqualityComparer` for your type `T`

Comment: Unfortunately to do this you first need to query DB to fetch values of `predicate2`...in practice vanishing any benefit (unless, of course, items must be heavily processed locally)

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, you can't compare *Predicate's content*, only *Predicate's reference*. So, to check if a Predicate *is child of* another, you can't directly check it.
However, you can check if a `List<Predicate<T>>` contains a *Predicate's reference*.

```
List<Predicate<T>> predicates = new List<Predicate<T>>();
Predicate<T> equalsOne = x => x == id1;
Predicate<T> equalsTwo = x => x == id2;
predicates.Add(equalsOne);
predicates.Add(equalsTwo);
IQueryable<T> predicate1 = someSource.Where(equalsOne);
IQueryable<T> predicate2 = someSource.Where(x => predicates.All(p => p(x)));
```

`predicates` **does** contain `equalsOne` and `equalsTwo`.
`predicates` **does not** contain `x => x == id1` nor `x => x == id2`.

---

**If you want a full class to simplify your `Where` method, you can use this:**

```
public sealed class PredicateCollection<T> : ICollection<Predicate<T>>
{
    #region PredicateCollection
    private List<Predicate<T>> Predicates { get; set; }
    public PredicateCollection() { Predicates = new List<Predicate<T>>(); }
    #endregion

    #region ICollection<Predicate<T>>
    public int Count { get { return Predicates.Count; } }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }
    public void Add(Predicate<T> item) { Predicates.Add(item); }
    public void Clear() { Predicates.Clear(); }
    public bool Contains(Predicate<T> item) { return Predicates.Contains(item); }
    public void CopyTo(Predicate<T>[] array, int arrayIndex) { Array.Copy(Predicates.ToArray(), 0, array, arrayIndex, Count); }
    public IEnumerator<Predicate<T>> GetEnumerator() { return Predicates.GetEnumerator(); }
    public bool Remove(Predicate<T> item) { return Predicates.Remove(item); }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return Predicates.GetEnumerator(); }
    #endregion

    #region PredicateCollection methods
    /// <summary>Check if any predicate is true</summary>
    public bool CheckAny(T item) { return Predicates.Any(predicate => predicate(item)); }
    /// <summary>Check if all predicates are true</summary>
    public bool CheckAll(T item) { return Predicates.All(predicate => predicate(item)); }
    /// <summary>Allow to use collection as predicate (check for all predicates)</summary>
    public static implicit operator Func<T, bool>(PredicateCollection<T> collection) { return item => collection.CheckAll(item); }
    #endregion
}
```

**And then use it like this:**

```
PredicateCollection<T> predicates = new PredicateCollection<T>();
Predicate<T> equalsOne = x => x == id1;
Predicate<T> equalsTwo = x => x == id2;
predicates.Add(equalsOne);
predicates.Add(equalsTwo);
IQueryable<T> predicate1 = someSource.Where(equalsOne);
IQueryable<T> predicate2 = someSource.Where(predicates);
```

Comment: The question is about expressions, not delegates, so the entire second half of your answer isn't applicable.