# Check if two Haskell functions are equal with regards to non-termination or errors

Tags: haskell, lambda, functional-programming

I'd like to know, i two Haskell functions are equal, also considering the case that the execution results in an error or does not terminate at all.

Example (these functions both take a function and a pair as arguments, apply the function to both members of the pair, and then return True if their results are the same, otherwise False):

```
tupleEqual, tupleEqual' :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> (a, a) -> Bool
tupleEqual f = (\(x,y) -> f x == f y)

tupleEqual' f (x, y) = f x == f y
```

My question is: how do I find out, how they functions would behave in case of non-termination or errors?

I know that the first function could be translated into

```
tupleEqual f = let fun (x,y) = f x == f y in fun
```

Could this be relevant?

Comment: Are you asking to decide whether a function terminates? This is the halting problem, and it is known to be undecidable -- there is no algorithm that can achieve that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: I get that. I'm just wondering how I can check whether or not two functions are equal. As in, does it make a difference, if I use a lambda abstraction - for example regarding how the compiler treats the function for inputs which don't terminate?

Comment: The equivalence of two arbitrary functions can be [reduced to halting problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132051/394253), so it is also undecidable

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to see how the two functions behave on partial inputs, you can supply the partial inputs yourself. For a pair, (let's say of type `(Int,Int)`), there are four different possibilities with regards to partiality.

```hs
( 1   , 1   ) -- Total
( _|_ , 1   ) -- Left bottom
( 1   , _|_ ) -- Right bottom
_|_           -- Bottom
```

You can use `undefined` as a bottom value, and test functions as you normally would in ghci. We'll test the `fst` function here as an example:

```hs
>>> fst (1,1)
1
>>> fst (undefined,1)
undefined
>>> fst (1,undefined)
1
>>> fst undefined
undefined
```

All of those are pretty obvious, so here's a slightly more interesting example.

```hs
mapFst :: (a -> b) -> (a, c) -> (b, c)
mapFst f (x, y) = (f x, y)

mapFst' :: (a -> b) -> (a, c) -> (b, c)
mapFst' f xy = (f (fst xy), snd xy)

>>> fst (mapFst (const 1) undefined)
undefined
>>> fst (mapFst' (const 1) undefined)
1
```

You could also have written `mapFst'` with an irrefutable pattern (`~(x,y)`).

Finally, if you want to test this as part of an automated testing framework, or you just want to do it more systematically, you can use the package [Chasing Bottoms](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ChasingBottoms).

Comment: Thank you very much. So if I got this right, in the above case none of the functions would even run with either input being undefined, so I could say they are equal? (Considering that they always return the same result given the same, valid input)

Comment: Not really. The two functions are equal, but not for the reason you've stated. If `f` didn't inspect its input, then both functions would return `True` for an input of `(undefined, undefined)`.